# Append in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this snippet in jQuery. I append an input text when a user clicks on an add sign that has an id 'clickEventOnPlus'. Within this appened code, there is a minus sign (defined in within ) that has another class clickEventOnMinus.

```
$('#clickEventOnPlus').click(function(){
   var addDestination2 = '<input type="text" <span><i style="font-size:18px" class="fa clickEventOnMinus">&#xf068;</i></span> <br> <br>'
   $(".addDestination").append(addDestination2);
});
```

How do I add an event listener on clickEventOnMinus? Because when I try the following code, it doesn't work. Thanks!

```
$('.clickEventOnMinus').click(function(){
     alert("W");
});
```

Comment: It should be `$(document).on("click",".clickEventOnMinus",function() {})`

Comment: Everyone else seems to have missed the fact you never close the `input` which could cause issues later if you plan to make use of it. `<input type="text" <span><i` is missing `/>` Example: `<input type="text"/> <span><i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yapu9a6m/10/) , be aware with the order of your code as the element is added to the DOM the event is added too

```
<div id="clickEventOnPlus">
hola
</div>
<div class="addDestination">

</div>
$('#clickEventOnPlus').click(function(){
   var addDestination2 = $('<input type="text" <span><i style="font-size:18px" class="fa clickEventOnMinus">&#xf068;</i></span> <br> <br>');
   $(".addDestination").append(addDestination2);
   console.log(addDestination2);
   $('.clickEventOnMinus').click(function(){
     alert("W");
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Another quick question - How would I delete a specific appened item? If I want to use the minus sign to delete that specific input text, how would I go about that?

Comment: @abidishajia with remove() https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: I added this, but it deletes all the appended input texts fields. I want it to delete a specific one.

`$('#clickEventOnPlus').click(function(){

var addDestination2 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Beijing, China" class="round removeDest" style="width:340px;" id="fieldThree"/>&nbsp; <span><i style="font-size:18px" class="fa clickEventOnMinus">&#xf068;</i></span> <br> <br>'

            $(".addDestination").append(addDestination2);

            $('.clickEventOnMinus').click(function(){
                $('.removeDest').remove();
            });

        }); `

@Álvaro Touzón

Answer (score 2):

we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickEventOnMinus', function() {
 alert("W");
});
```

Comment: no need to answer dup questions

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `.click` after the element appended, otherwise, the selector cannot found the element

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#clickEventOnPlus').click(function(){
           var addDestination2 = '<input type="text" <span><i style="font-size:18px" class="fa clickEventOnMinus">&#xf068;</i></span> <br> <br>'
           $(".addDestination").append(addDestination2);

            $('.clickEventOnMinus').click(function(){
                 alert("W");
            });
        });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".addDestination").on('click', '.clickEventOnMinus', function(){
     alert("W");
});
```

Comment: no need to answer dup questions

Comment: using a smaller scope than `document` is better at performance. but you have to add an explanation to the answer.